# issue importing module in python jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, module, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

hi so I'm trying to import geopandas into my script

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

#handling txt
#remove 'lat=' and 'long=' then type change from object to float to make point.
df = pd.read_csv('latlong.txt', header=None, names = ['lat','long', 'name','description'])

df['lat'] = df['lat'].str.replace('lat=', '')
df['long'] = df['long'].str.replace('long=', '')

df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype(float)
df['long'] = df['long'].astype(float)

#make point geometry
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(low['long'], low['lat']), axis=1) #long is X, lat is Y

#change df to gdf
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry', crs='EPSG:4326')  #epsg4326 is WGS84
```

But when I try to run this in the jupyter notebook, using a conda environment from these steps: https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084

I get the following error :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2312/3230284861.py in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import geopandas as gpd
      3 from shapely.geometry import Point
      4 
      5 #handling txt

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     14 
     15 if missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\geojsongen\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed the geopandas in this environment using the following command:
`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

Could someone advise me on how I can fix these errors? Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

edit:
I tried this `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`, thanks @krmogi for this, but now I get this error, it looks like an issue with my geopandas installation? :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13932/3230284861.py in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import geopandas as gpd
      3 from shapely.geometry import Point
      4 
      5 #handling txt

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
      2 
      3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
      4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
      5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py in <module>
    107 use_pygeos = Option(
    108     key="use_pygeos",
--> 109     default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
    110     doc=(
    111         "Whether to use PyGEOS to speed up spatial operations. The default is True "

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_config.py in _default_use_pygeos()
     93 
     94 def _default_use_pygeos():
---> 95     import geopandas._compat as compat
     96 
     97     return compat.USE_PYGEOS

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_compat.py in <module>
      7 import numpy as np
      8 import pandas as pd
----> 9 import pyproj
     10 import shapely
     11 import shapely.geos

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import warnings
     48 
---> 49 import pyproj.network
     50 from pyproj._datadir import (  # noqa: F401 pylint: disable=unused-import
     51     _pyproj_global_context_initialize,

~\.conda\envs\geojsongen\lib\site-packages\pyproj\network.py in <module>
      8 import certifi
      9 
---> 10 from pyproj._network import (  # noqa: F401 pylint: disable=unused-import
     11     _set_ca_bundle_path,
     12     is_network_enabled,

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _network: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is happening here as shown in your traceback

```
----> 1 import pandas as pd
```

Make sure you have `pandas` installed.

```
pip install pandas
```

It also says that `numpy` C-extentions failed. Install `numpy` as well:

```
pip install numpy
```

While you're at it, make sure you have the other modules installed as well.

If you're still getting the same error, it's possible that `setuptools` is not properly installed. Do this:

1. `pip uninstall -y numpy`
2. `pip uninstall -y setuptools`
3. `pip install setuptools`
4. `pip install numpy`

If you still don't have any luck, try this:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```

Comment: thanks! i did these but the error still persists :(  is a reboot required?

Comment: np :) It shouldn't, but still try it.

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look at it.

Comment: thanks it fixed, should I do something similar for geopandas? because now my geopandas seems to be throwing some errors too :( [added the error to the  original post]

Comment: ok I fixed some, but seems like it's having problems installing Fiona :( and I tried the above method for Fiona too

Comment: Look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394120/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-while-imp